# Translate a Java anonymous callback class to C#

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

I'm a beginner with Xamarin Android and I must to test the scanner of the phone Honeywell Dolphin CT 50.

My project compile well, I've well add the jar library from honey well but my problem now is some Java code.

I can't translate it into C#!

Here is it the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // create the AidcManager providing a Context and a
    // CreatedCallback implementation.
    AidcManager.create(this, new CreatedCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCreated(AidcManager aidcManager) {
            manager = aidcManager;
            barcodeReader = manager.createBarcodeReader();
        }
    });

    ActivitySetting();
}
```

My problem is to translate the second parameter of the method:

```
AidcManager.create => new CreatedCallback() ?
```

How can I translate this to C#?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a lambda, but that would fall apart as soon as you had more than one method to override. A separate class is the way to handle the general case:

```
public virtual void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ContentView = R.layout.activity_main;

    // create the AidcManager providing a Context and a
    // CreatedCallback implementation.
    AidcManager.create(this, new CreatedCallbackAnonymousInnerClassHelper());

    ActivitySetting();
}

private class CreatedCallbackAnonymousInnerClassHelper : CreatedCallback
{
    public override void onCreated(AidcManager aidcManager)
    {
        manager = aidcManager;
        barcodeReader = manager.createBarcodeReader();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello dave, thanks for your time i've implements your code but that's doesn't work if i put a break point into onCreated of the class Helper i visual studio never stop ...

Comment: sorry it's my first time in stack over flow but how i can post a comment with code ?

Comment: @tapastoutvu: I don't think this is a conversion issue. If your code has a 'CreatedCallback' class, then this class should be raising events that the overridden 'onCreated' method will catch.

Comment: Hello dan, thanks for your time but how i can raising an events ? here is it the class :using Com.Honeywell.Aidc;
namespace HoneyWellCT50
{
    public class CreatedCallbackAnonymousInnerClassHelper : Com.Honeywell.Aidc.AidcManager.ICreatedCallback
    {
        public void OnCreated(AidcManager aidcManager)
        {
            MainActivity.manager = aidcManager;
            MainActivity.barcodeReader = MainActivity.manager.CreateBarcodeReader();
        }
        public IntPtr Handle { get; set; }
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }
    }

Comment: and my activity : public virtual void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            //
            Button btnActive = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnActive);
            btnActive.Click += BtnActive_Click;

            //
            AidcManager.Create(this, new CreatedCallbackAnonymousInnerClassHelper());

Comment: Hello dave, that work now :) i'm so happy  ..for to resolve my problem here is it the step : AidcManager.Create(this, this);  reader.AddBarcodeListener(this as BarcodeReader.IBarcodeListener);
reader.AddTriggerListener(this as BarcodeReader.ITriggerListener);
reader.Claim();  after add authorizatrion in manifest as : <uses-permission android:name="com.honeywell.decode.permission.DECODE"/>  after all work fine thanks for your help Sorry i can't find how to add a new message with code